# Can you damage logic gates by connecting two outputs together and powering one?

Tags: logic-gates, logic-level, polarity

As the title says, would this cause problems in a circuit, and if so, how do you get around it (other than connecting them both through an OR gate)?

[image: Two gates whose outputs are connected]

Furthermore, could you stop this with a buffer? Can a buffer act as a diode (at least not die)?

Comment: A Schottky diode on each output and you are safe. Even if it may not cause any problem.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! But could I use a buffer?

Comment: How to get around this? Never connect active output to active output, unless they are open-drain/collectors. Most schematic capture tools wouldn't allow you to do such silly thing.

Comment: Use of a Schottky diode requires a pull-up or pull-down resistor.

Comment: @Andev  I use an bonafide OR gate in a situation like this.  Is there a reason why you can't have an OR gate IC?  Few more questions.  Why would one output be powered and other not powered?  Aren't both of them powered by the same power supply?  Or, do you actually mean "logic high" when you say "powered"?

Comment: It is very rare for there to be any good reason to connect two outputs together. Why are you doing it in the first place? Even putting aside the question of one unit being powered and the other not?

Comment: There are many ways to solve the problem. But having two outputs connected together is suspicious in the first place. So I would like to hear more about what is going on.

Comment: I'm writing a logic gate simulator, so I want to make sure it's accurate. Right now, you can't connect more than one output to a wire so I'll probably just leave it like that!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use open drain logic gates with a pullup resistor. The obvious question is what do you expect to happen when you connect your logic gates together?

Comment: Smoke! But I have to make sure

Answer (score 1):

Generic logic, usually CMOS nowadays, does not tolerate
outputs connected together, and powering down one chip at
a time is a practice that violates datasheet warnings.

Outputs that are intended to share output wires are not usually implemented in 
logic that is powered OFF, but rather are connected to logic
that is capable of achieving high output impedance (so-called tri-state
outputs).   Buffers of the tri-state type [74BCT245 for example](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74bct245.pdf) are often used
for connecting to multiple-master buses, like the familiar ISA
bus of old PCs.

In previous generations of logic, open-collector outputs also
allowed multiple drivers (but required a pullup resistor solution).
HP-IB (IEEE-488) and single-ended SCSI relied on this.  Collisions
were possible, and detection of such was part of the communication
protocol.

Ethernet standards for thickwire and thinwire (10base5 and 10base2)
used a current-value signalling scheme to allow multidevice wiring with
collision detection; this was a kind of multivalued logic, not
the gate logic that has two states.

Modern differential signaling can be similarly made to 
be multiple-driver capable (ultra SCSI, IEEE-485 multidrop serial,
are examples) by a tri-state scheme, with termination resistance
usually included.

Answer (score 1):

Can the unpowered IC be damaged? Yes. It could be. And on top of that, it can also load the output of the other IC so that the logic output state is not correct. In other words, if one IC is powered up and tries to drive the output high, the other IC may load the output and prevent it from reaching its full high logic output voltage.

However, there is a logic family that is specifically designed so that you can apply voltage to the outputs even when the IC is not powered up. The inputs and outputs will not be damaged, and will maintain high impedance until VCC comes up.

The other problem with connecting outputs together has nothing to do with separate power domains. The problem is that if they ever drive to opposite states (one high and one low) then the actual output state will be undetermined, and one or both may be damaged, either immediately or over time. This is why I am so skeptical of the whole question.

If you are still interested, the search terms you can use to find these special gates are "partial-power-down" and "Ioff." I think those are TI proprietary terms, but there are other vendors as well. Here is one example part: TI part number SN74LVC1G08DBVR.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I am making virtual gates and want to simulate them accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on getting the heat out, to protect the output CMOS devices. And if you
have tiny output devices (small W/L), the currents will be small and the heat generation will not be a problem.

Summary ... depends on the FET sizes.